# How to round a number bigger than long type max value in Java?

Tags: java, type-conversion, rounding

I've to **handle really big double values** and I have to round them to the next full number. If I round the double value I always receive the value **9.223372036854776E18** which happens to be the maximum long value. How do I round values bigger than this?

**Edit:** Just for clarification: I'm not a Java programmer and come from the C front. I'm helping a friend on this case. I tried unsigned (obviously didn't work), googled and found BigDecimal and BigInteger. Tried casting them and it happened to crash. That's why I came here. Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`BigDecimal` would be the solution to contain values larger than long.

Read this [BigDecimal javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)

You need to instantiate `BigDecimal(yourDoubleValue);` not casting.

Comment: I already tried casting the double value to BigDecimal and BigInteger. But it crashed every time.

Comment: Please provide exception message and the code you have tried.

Comment: @Tom: There is no such thing as casting between a primitive and a reference type. You should be doing `BigDecimal.valueOf(doubleValue)`;

Answer (score 3):

In essence:

```
Math.floor(d+0.5)
```

but you have to adjust to subtraction if `d` is negative.

Comment: This is actually the simplest solution for my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)

- [How to use BigDecimal](http://www.opentaps.org/docs/index.php/How_to_Use_Java_BigDecimal%3a_A_Tutorial)

e.g.

```
BigDecimal decimalA = new BigDecimal("98765432123456789");
```

Answer (score 2):

BigDecimal can hold any double and float value.  To convert from a double to a BigDecimal, use code like this:

```
double reallyBigDouble
BigDecimal x = new BigDecimal(reallyBigDouble);
```

To round to the nearest integer value, you could use code like this:

```
BigDecimal roundedToInteger = x.round(new MathContext(MathContext.UNLIMITED));
```

Answer (score 2):

Any `double` value too large to fit into a `long` already represents an integer value, and rounding it will have no effect.  This is because a double only holds 52 bits of precision on its significand, and a long holds 64 -- so if the value is too big for a `long`, the `double` doesn't have enough precision left to hold any fractional parts.